# FAB в Android Studio налаживается на BottomNavigationView

Tags: android-studio, android-navigation-view

Всем привет. У меня в проекте есть BottomNavigationView, но проблема в том, что при добавлении FAB и закреплении его в нижней правой области, он не видит "BottomNavigationView" и налагается на него...

Фото: [image: Фиолетовая стрелка как есть, а зеленая схема, как по идее должно быть]

Код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?        
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:contentDescription="Test"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно контейнер в котором находится кнопка разместить выше чем нижнее меню и сделать wrap_content:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:contentDescription="Test"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

как-то так должно быть по логике :)